# Python - Adding something to a list only once

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

my problem is that I only want to add the string "Karte1" once to a list. But right now, the string "Karte1" is adding to a list unlimited times..
Hope u can help me :)

```
import random

Deck1 = []

def startgame():
    try:
        "Karte1" not in Deck1
        if True:
            Deck1.append("Karte1")
        if False:
            pass
    except:
        pass


while True:
    startgame()
    print(Deck1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a set if you want unique values.

But in your case just change your code to:

```
if "Karte1" not in Deck1:
    Deck1.append("Karte1")
```

**EDIT:**

Notice that in your while statement you call to the function **startgame2**, when the name of the function you defined is **startgame**

Comment: Thanks, that worked. One more question: Is there a way to test it for multiple lists at one time? Edit: Yea, just cut it out of my main source, its not that big problem^^ Fixed it in the main post

Comment: @HealYouDown , You can use the zip function in order to loop through several lists. `if len([1 for item1, item2, item3 in zip(li1, li2, l3) if "Karte1" not in li1 and "Karte1" not in li2 and "Karte1" not in li3]) > 0: ...`.  Thanks for accepting :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set data structure rather than a list.
A set holds unique values, by default.

**From Python Docs**

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

> The sets module provides classes for constructing and manipulating unordered collections of **unique elements**. Common uses include membership testing, **removing duplicates** from a sequence, and computing standard math operations on sets such as intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference.

**Example**

```
my_set = set([1,2,3,2])
print(my_set)    # prints [1,2,3]

my_set.add(4)
print(my_set)    # prints [1,2,3,4]

my_set.add(3)
print(my_set)    # prints [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if True`statement will allways be True, so each time you call the `startgame()`function it will add it to the `Deck`

What you probably want to do is :`

```
if "Karte1" not in Deck1:
     Deck1.append("Karte1")
```